# How to make a text website hostile only to machine-learning models while maintaining smooth experience for humans?

Tags: web-crawlers, website-design

So, we're building a website that showcases some niche information and tries to present it in a way to build up a knowledge base. We want to maximize accessibility to people and spider bots, while introducing as many barriers to large language models. Any tips?

I've been reading up on how to guard against web-scrapers and the like, and I've found a lot of great information, but they aren't really an issue as far as this website is concerned. The website is supposed to be a repository of knowledge ( that just so also happens to serves a publicity purpose), and it is crucial for it to be easily accessible by people (without having to captcha or login).

On the other hand, if we can't find a way to stop successors of ChatGPT from training on the text of our website, we'll have to seriously amend our business model (or UX).

So we've been trying to work out if we can possibly make it so that our site's text is accessible to people and even bots, while being useless (preferably even hostile) if used in as training data for a model.

Comment: If there are no other suggestions. Maybe, asking for captcha once and store a longer term cookie.  Or count/time consecutive accesses and just slow it down.

Comment: You may or may not also get some traction by looking at the user agent and/or using robots.txt file - of-course, these assume the robots are acting ethically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We want to maximize accessibility to people and spider bots, while introducing as many barriers to large language models.

> it is crucial for it to be easily accessible by people (without having to captcha or login)

If bots can read your site, then data can be extracted. And if data can be extracted, then that data can be fed into a machine learning model. Unless it chooses to identify itself, a spider bot that's gathering data for acceptable purposes is indistinguishable from a bot that's gathering data for machine learning purposes - the only difference is who the bots give the data to after they've gathered it, which is beyond anyone's control.

If you try to obfuscate your data in such a way that a real person would still be able to read it and understand it without much trouble, the machine learning model will also be smart enough to read it and understand it without much trouble. Such is the nature of machine learning. There is no way around that.

As far as I know, there's also no way to create a "poison pill" of sorts like you're implying - i.e. a piece of text that itself defends against or damages the AI that is reading it. And if there was, then it would be considered a bug and the developer of the AI could easily patch it. So the protections necessarily need to be not in the data itself or the data format, but in how the data is accessed, i.e. your server software as the gatekeeper.

In my eyes, the only complete solutions will naturally involve whitelists, blacklists, fragile heuristic checks, and/or other band-aid solutions that might delay what I believe is the inevitable subsumption of the entire human-readable internet into ML models. Here are some ideas:

- Do you need to allow all non-ML spider bots to crawl your site, or do you really just want your site indexed on search engines? If the latter, consider using your `robots.txt` file to disallow bots except for named search engine bots. Then, to reinforce this policy by detecting and blocking bots that do not conform, use server-side software to filter out bots that do not verifiably originate from search engine IPs ([googlebot](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/verifying-googlebot) and [bingbot](https://www.bing.com/webmasters/help/how-to-verify-bingbot-3905dc26) IPs, for starters).
- As Rohit Gupta mentioned in the comments, consider strictly limiting the speed at which non-search-engine bots are allowed to crawl your site. You can use the [429 status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) to indicate when they should back off. But this is a mitigation against all bots, not just bots that are gathering data for ML training. It's the opposite of maximizing accessibility to spider bots as you desire.
- Try playing around with something like [reCAPTCHA v3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3), which scores users based on probability that they are a bot. There may be a cutoff score where you can offer your website to legitimate visitors, while blocking most bots. Though this also compromises the ability for spider bots to crawl your site, which you've stated is not desirable.
- To implement all this bot filtering, third party bot management software like [Cloudflare Bot Management](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/bot-management/) might help. Ironically, they detect and classify bots by using machine learning.
- For any ML bots that play nicely by identifying themselves and respecting the `robots.txt` standard, you can block them by name in your `robots.txt` file.

In summary, categorically maximizing accessibility to non-ML spider bots while minimizing accessibility to ML spider bots is a non-starter (because the difference isn't in their crawling behavior but in what they do with the data afterwards), but hopefully some of these ideas were helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question though, is there a way to force the ML model to credit our site properly ? You may assume that across the internet, our site's paragraphs are unique.

Comment: @4amvim There is no technical way to force an ML model to credit your website, no more than there is a way to force any other piece of computer code running on someone else's computer to do what you want it to. Somewhat like humans, I don't believe current ML models even have direct and full awareness of "where they heard of" a piece of information, e.g. which data from their training set they pieced together to make a certain inference. But even if they did, the developer could program the model to not respond with source information, or even to deliberately lie.